# Problems setting git up locally/remotely (with Coda 2 and Terminal)

Tags: git, version-control, coda

I'm trying to set up Git for better version control on my current site build (this is my first time using Git) - I've just been manually duplicating files and I feel that Git's commit system is a much better solution.

I'm running MacOS 10.11, and have installed Git using Xcode. On my remote server I used the following commands using Terminal in an SSH session:

```
mkdir ~/.git
cd ~/.git; mkdir project.git; cd project.git
git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/.git/project.git/.git/
```

On my local system I used `$which git` Which returned `/usr/bin/git`

I then used the `git init` command on my local machine, which returned `initialized Git repository in /Users/user/.git/`. So far, so good.

Then I used the following command `git remote set-url origin ssh://username@site.com:/home/.git/project.git` (obviously with the correct user details)

Using `git remote -v` gets me:

```
git remote -v
origin  ssh://username@site.com:/home/.git/project.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://username@site.com:/home/.git/project.git (push)
```

so all seems to be working. The problem comes here. In Coda 2 in the source tab I only have 'local' showing and no remote drop down.

Additionally in Terminal, if I try and use the command `git push origin --all` I get the following error:

```
stdin: is not a tty
fatal: '/home/.git/project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Does anyone have any idea where I am going wrong? I'm assuming its something simple but I've read through lots of similar answers on here and been unable to identify the problem. I've also tried reinitialising the git dir to no joy!

Comment: As a side-note: 1) A repo that nobody works on, but is just used for pushing/pulling, should be `--bare`. The extension `.git` for folders should also be reserved for bare repos. 2) You made your whole home directory a git repository. Is that really intended? Instead, you probably wanted `git init project`—or `cd project && git init`.

Comment: No I didn't mean to make my whole home directory a repo! How can I undo this?

Comment: If you simply want to delete all commits/branches/your complete history, and only leave your working directory as-is, a `rm -rf .git/` will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I solved this by taking the following steps from scratch -

I created a new git repository on my Server by SSHing in to my box and using the following

```
mkdir git
cd git
git init --bare project.git
```

Once that was done I created a new root directory on my local machine for files and using terminal cloned the remote git repository

```
git clone ssh://user@example.com/path/to/project.git 
cd project
```

1. I then set everything up within Coda and used this as local root as 
   my file directory. This gave me 'local' in version control but not
   remote.
2. I edited my files in Coda and added them to the repository using the
   SCM sidebar.
3. Once they were added I pushed them to the server using a terminal
   command and then went back to coda, saved, quit the site and then my
   'remote' folder appeared in the Source tab within the site set-up.

All seems to be working and giving me push and pull!

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the beginning, shall we?

On a remote repository, you need to initialize git as a bare repo like so:

```
git init --bare
```

A bare git repo is a directory with only the .git directory. No working area files. If you didn't specify the `--bare` option, you will get an error message every time you push saying that you are trying to modify files on the remote repo.

After you initialize the remote repo, you can easily clone the repo on your local machine like so:

```
git clone username@hostname:/path/to/.git
```

the `username` is the server login username. The `hostname` is the domain name or the server ip.